# trouble using str.center() with unicode characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I observed this strange behaviour of `center` method of `str` objects in `python 2.7` -

```
>>> print '-'.center(5,'.')        # '-' is the minus or hyphen key on the keyboard.
..-..                              # correctly centered
>>> print '─'.center(5, '.')       # '─' is NOT the minus or hyphen key on the keyboard.
.─.                                # incorrectly centered
```

Is this a bug in the implementation of `center` method or has something to do with the use of unicode characters?
How do I fix this?

[Note that this works perfectly fine in `python 3.2`]

Comment: Have you tried u"─"? The character you're using is 3 bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: `u"─"` works. Thank you. But I wanted to know the reason for this strange behaviour. Post that as an answer and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, there's a distinction between the `str` and `unicode` types. A `str` is a sequence of bytes and is created with un-modified quotes. Your `'─'` is creating a sequence of 3 bytes which display as a single unicode character; when you ask `str.center()` to center those bytes in a field 5 bytes wide, it adds a single byte on either side; when printed you only get 3 glyphs.

If you create a `unicode` object (with `u'─'` or '─'.decode('utf-8')), you now have a sequence of 1 unicode character, which will be centered by adding 2 characters to either side.

Python 3 doesn't have this problem, because ordinary strings are unicode character sequences.

Answer (score 2):

```
print '─'.decode('utf-8').center(5, '.')  

# returns: '..─..'
```

Comment: can I know the reason for this strange behaviour when not using `decode` (ie why is it giving incorrect output instead of giving an error)?

Comment: It does not interpret the '─' the way you would probably want it to.